# Migrating code from VS 2005 to 2013 causes error LNK1104 error?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to migrate a solution file from VS 2005 to VS 2013. The majority of the projects within the solutions rebuilt just fine.

However, some of the projects are coming up with the error:

> error LINK1104: cannot open file 'mfc80.lib'

I have searched for **mfc80.lib** on my computer and it does not exist.

[image]

I cannot follow the solution from here [fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gdi32.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599723/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-gdi32-lib) because the file does not exist, therefore I cannot add its path in "Additional Library Directories".

I have:

1. Deleted all the .obj and .lib files for the problematic project
2. Ensured Visual C++ MFC MBCS Library for Visual Studio 2013 is installed
3. Followed [Error LNK1104 cannot open file ';.obj'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462752/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-obj)

What else do I need to check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your project is attempting to include `mfc80.lib` explicitly. This is the version that VS2005 used; you need `mfc120.lib`.

Also, double-check that none of your source has a declaration like the following: `#define _MFC_FILENAME_VER`

Comment: I dont see `mfc90.lib`, I only see `mfc120.lib` in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64` directory. I'm not familiar with VS, how do I point it to `mfc120.lib`?

Comment: @Pangu I misread what version you were trying to link against. Answer still stands.